# Setting Thumbnails for Google Classroom Coursework

Tags: google-api-client, google-classroom

We've been trying to get the custom coursework thumbnail working and have been unsuccessful so far.  We've tried both a page URL and a url directly to a thumbnail image.  We're using the PHP client like so:

```
...
$materialLink = new Google_Service_Classroom_Link();
$materialLink->setUrl("https://www.oursite.net");
$materialLink->setThumbnailUrl("https://i.ytimg.com/vi/m9We2XsVZfc/hqdefault.jpg");
$materials = new Google_Service_Classroom_Material();
$materials->setLink($materialLink);
...
```

However, instead of the custom thumbnail showing, the default (a snapshot of our crawled site) always shows as the the coursework thumbnail.

Has anyone successfully used the custom thumbnail feature?

Comment: I think this is an intended behavior, as this [reported issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36760877): both the title and thumbnailUrl fields are read-only (in other words, you cannot set or modify them). I wasn't able to see if there where any feature request posted but feel free to create one just like the Googler mentioned. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It's read-only. (thanks Mr.Rebot).  The documentation notes that but it didn't resonate because you can set the thumbnail URL utilizing the methods,  which seems a bit odd.